# Python Efficiency of the in statement

Tags: python, performance

Just a quick question, I know that when looking up entries in a dictionary there's a fast efficient way of doing it:

(Assuming the dictionary is ordered in some way using `collections.OrderedDict()`)
You start at the middle of the dictionary, and find whether the desired key is off to one half or another, such as when testing the position of a name in an alphabetically ordered dictionary (or in rare cases dead on). You then check the next half, and continue this pattern until the item is found (meaning that with a dictionary of 1000000 keys you could effectively find any key within 20 iterations of this algorithm).

So I was wondering, if I were to use an `in` statement (i.e. `if a in somedict:`), would it use this same method of checking for the desired key? Does it use a faster/slower algorithm?

Comment: Dictionaries are hash maps. You will just slow down the lookup.

Comment: dude, you are going in wrong direction, you may require to read this http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/

Comment: You're describing binary search.  Dicts use hashing, which is usually much faster than binary search.  If you have a sorted list, though, you can use the `bisect` module to perform a binary search on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Python's dictionaries basically use a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (it actually uses an modified hash table to improve speed) (I won't bother to explain a hash table; the linked Wikipedia article describes it well) which is a neat structure which allows ~O(1) (very fast) access. `in` looks up the object (the same thing that dict[object] does) except it doesn't return the object, which is the most optimal way of doing it.

The [code for `in` for dictionaries](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/953d8ec1aeb3/Objects/dictobject.c#l2186) contains this line (`dk_lookup()` returns a hash table entry if it exists, otherwise NULL (the equivalent of None in C, often indicating an error)):

`ep = (mp->ma_keys->dk_lookup)(mp, key, hash, &value_addr);`

Comment: Not really O(1). Someting between O(1) and O(n).